# What are possible trajectory azimuths at Wallops?

Tags: launch, trajectory

I note that the NASA page on Wallops trajectories has a disclaimer saying that the page has not been updated and is for historical purposes only. Are the northern-most trajectories still restricted to 90 degrees azimuth avoiding launches over Assateague National Seashore?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page please?

Comment: http://www.nasa.gov/centers/wallops/about/launchrange.html